# PHP Search bar not returning any result

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to build an online shop, the database is connected no problem and I am able to display the data on the Webpage. I have also created a full product page which also working and displaying the correct data. However I have built a search bar where if you type in a product number or name it goes to the full product page displaying the full data of what you have searched for however no data is being outputted.

```
<?php
global $ConnectingDB;
if (isset($_GET["SearchButton"])) {
   $Search = $_GET["Search"];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productNumber LIKE '%$Search%' OR productName LIKE 
   '%$Search%' OR briefProductInfo LIKE '%$Search%'";
   $stmt = $ConnectingDB->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   if ($DataRows = $stmt->fetch()) {
      do {
         $ProductNumber = $DataRows["productNumber"];
         Redirect_to("fullSpecs.php?productNumber=$ProductNumber");
     } while ($DataRows = $stmt->fetch());
     } else {
         $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="No Record Found, please try another search!";
         Redirect_to("computerStore.php?page=1");
     }      
  }
?>

<form method="get" action="fullSpecs.php">
     <div class="form-group">            
        <input class="form-control mb-2" type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search by Product Name or 
        Number" value="">
        <button class="btn btn-success" name="SearchButton" style="width: 100%;">Search</button>            
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to redirect from inside a _loop_? That makes rather little sense to begin with.

Comment: (And I hope you are not under the impression, that your SQL queries were “safe”, just because you used `$ConnectingDB->prepare($sql)`? They are not.)

Comment: I did manage to get the search button working this way before on a different project but I could not figure out why nothing was being returned on this one. Are you saying a loop is not the right way to go about this

Comment: I am saying, if you don’t ever expect more than one result record, then you don’t need to use a loop in the first place. And if there could be more than one result - well then redirecting makes little sense to begin with, you can not redirect to multiple pages at once.

Comment: ok will get rid of the loop and try something else, yeah only wanted one record to appear on the full product page. Thanks